# Vox Populi badge is missing from the Vote Up page

Tags: support, status-completed, badges

**[Vox Populi](https://superuser.com/badges/110/vox-populi)** badge is missing from the [Vote up questions and answers](https://superuser.com/privileges/vote-up) information page.

Comment: It's a rather new badge, since the maximum was 30 until some time ago, so they probably just forgot to add it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Privilege pages are essentially Wikis and [can be edited](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80019/ability-to-edit-privileges-pages) by anyone having the required rep.

I have updated the privilege page on Meta.Stack Overflow, they should be propagated to all sites soon.